# How do eap and eap tls differs?

Tags: security, ssl

I understand that eap tls is a transport layer security function. But even after searching in google some lack of clarity remains.

Is the eap tls a special implementation of the general eap protocol definition? Or eap tls is another layer above the eap , as in a protocol stack?

What eap does? Is it just a message framing protocol for eap tls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLS is most often used for two reasons.  The client wants to insure that is communicating with the correct server,  and that the communication between these two nodes is a secret.  In vanilla (non-EAP) SSL/TLS you can still authenticate the client using a private key.  However in practice it is difficult for a user to keep track of a private key (Usually a client is issued a smart card).  Authenticating with a private key alone may not be appropriate for the situation.

However, lets say a corporation wants to authenticate its employees for access to its VPN or Wireless Network.  Fundamentally this entity wants to control who has access to this transport layer (osi layer 4).  A common use of TLS-EAP is that it allows an entity to use a Radius Authentication Server with an LDAP backend to authenticate its employees with a username a password.  For added security the corporation could employe multi-facotor authentication,  where an iris scan,  a smart card with a private key and password is required.   EAP,  is the "Extensible Authentication Protocol" and you can choose what authentication system to use.  Its not always stronger,  there could be a vulnerability in the Radius server that allows the client to authenticate.

Hell if you write the code for it,  you could use EAP-TLS to create some authentication system for your network involving a flair gun,  smoke signals and a special handshake.  From EAP-TLS's perspective the means of authentication is totally arbitrary.